# How to get url of website?

Tags: android

In my android application I have opened some website. I want to share the url link of website on facebbok through my application. How can I do it. I can share url link to facebook by given code.

```
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET); 

    // Add data to the intent, the receiving app will decide
    // what to do with it.
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Title Of The Post");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "url link");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share link!"));
```

But how to get the url link which I am browsing.

Comment: Show us **how** you are presenting this link. Then I can show you the different methods to get the URL

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the "url" what you are going to hit in browser?
From your android application surely u will give some url link to browse.
just save that url as a string,and you can easily share the string.otherwise,if you are in browser or browsing webview contents means,you can use webview.getUrl() method .suppose this is not what you asked means,please update your question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) in your application then you can use [`geUrl();`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl%28%29) method to get the URL of the current page